# SetWindowsHookEx DLL unloading

Tags: c++, winapi, dll-injection

I am using SetWindowsHookEx to inject a dll into another process. However, when the injector program exits, the dll is unloaded from the other process. Is there anyway for me to stop the unloading ? Basically, I want the dll to persist permanently regardless of whether the injector program is still running. If I am able to increase the dll reference count from within the dll, that could work. But I haven't found a way.

Comment: for increase the dll reference count - `LdrAddRefDll(0, &__ImageBase);`

Comment: Thanks. I put your suggestion in Visual Studio, but these names are not known. Is there an include file I have to use ?

Comment: declare it by self and use ntdll.lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

exist 2 way
1.) most effective - use [LdrAddRefDll](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d7/d55/ldrapi_8c.html#ad0f51f578765130a71065cd878fb9643) - this do exactly what you need in shortest way. you need use ntdll.lib (or ntdllp.lib) for linking.

```
LdrAddRefDll(0, (HMODULE)&__ImageBase);
```

2)not nice and effective but work

```
WCHAR sz[MAX_PATH];
if (GetModuleFileName((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, sz, RTL_NUMBER_OF(sz)))
{
    LoadLibrary(sz);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was in the middle of writing 2). Now I will just copy and paste :). As for 1), that looks complicated. I will use it if 2) doesn't work.

Comment: both 1 and 2 work of course. both add reference to dll which hold it from unload - need extra FreeLibrary now. but 1 - do this direct. 2 first translate &__ImageBase to name, then translate name to same __ImageBase and finally add reference

Comment: Success. I used 2 because I didn't have to change the linker settings - I don't even know where that is. DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH gave me the dll handle that I feed into GetModuleFileName. The module was loaded from a new thread in case of dead locks in DllMain.

Comment: As always, when proposing to use undocumented function calls, make sure to add a disclaimer to that effect. The solution may not be available on all versions of Windows, and can stop working at any time, without prior notice.

Comment: @IInspectable - about versions - in work on win2000 (may be and nt 4.0), xp, 2003, vista, win7, win 8.1, win 10, .. but may not be available.. in this sense all sometime can stop work

Comment: There is no documented contract for functions internal to the OS. That makes them completely different from the documented API surface, that comes with guarantees. Those will not suddenly stop working, and in the rare case that they do, it is documented, so you know about it. What's so hard to understand about this?